# IDEA: previous commands in console

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console

I am using IntelliJ IDEA version 11. And debugging my application using console.

Is it possible to use previous commands like in Linux shell with up arrow?
Also it would be great if I can prepare a list of commands and then select them in a smart way.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that this is not possible.

For accepting user input(e.g. System.in), one can use either the built in console or one can even add an external command line tool as [described here in the documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-command-line-tool-commands.html). In  Windows, I was able to successfully add the standard DOS prompt command line program to IntelliJ and use that to issue any commands that would be accepted by the OS, but even in that case, you do not have command history or autocomplete as [discussed here](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/293590)

In the [Editor setting](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/editor.html), I see a setting "Console commands history size", but setting this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but what console are you talking about? Debug console is output only, and command line console (which is not bundled with IDEA anyway) does have the arrow feature you asked.

Comment: Depending on programming language used, you can have several different interactive consoles in Idea workspace and each one can be used in the debugging process. This question is tagged with 'console' but doesn't say which console it is about. Why the downvote?

Comment: Downvote is not mine, but you shloud've posted this as a comment.

Comment: Yeah, sadly this privilege requires reputation of 50. I was hoping that the vote was caused by some serious flaw in my approach to answering/understanding this question, and that's why I'm drilling for the explanation. But you may be right and this may be about formalities. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I run my program, there is console shown and I can input commands to System.in. In IDEA 11 I don't see how to use right arrow to select previous command.